# Android - Open file with QFile

Tags: android, qt, qfile

After recording a video with the Camera on an Android device, the actualLocation is file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/VID_00000012.3gp

How can I open it?

```
  QFile videoLocation;
  videoLocation.setFileName(actualLocation);
  if (videoLocation.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
      ...
  }
  else {
      qDebug() << videoLocation.errorString();
  }
```

The open method fails and the errorString prints *No such file or directory*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QFile expects a path, not an URL. Try removing the `file://` at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you, it's right. I've done this: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/65521-Android-Open-file-with-QFile?p=288923#post288923